# check the data coming from arduino to android via USB host

Tags: android

My code receive data on my Android phone from Arduino via USB host.
The data (in form of bytes) is transformed to String Output, I write code in the method updateReceivedData(byte[]) that checks if the data contains "Warning" word, to send message containing the warning data

I try to make counter to make delay between sending messages in case of continuous warning received data, then I would to reset the counter if there is no warning message

My problem is that the counter reset every time and continue sending message without making delay.

I think the solution is by making delay while The String output is completed, then check on it, but I don't know how?

```
private void updateReceivedData(byte[] data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String Output = new String(data);
    if(Output.contains("Warning")){
        if (warncounter==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Warning message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, Output, null, null);          
        }
        warncounter++;
        if(warncounter==52) warncounter=0;
    }
    else warncounter=0;
    mDumpTextView.append(Output);
    mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mDumpTextView.getBottom());
    }
```

To make an approach for finding the problem, I try this code

```
private void updateReceivedData(byte[] data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String Output = new String(data);
    if(Output.contains("Warning")){
              SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, Output, null, null);
            }
    }
    mDumpTextView.append(Output);
    mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mDumpTextView.getBottom());
    }
```

In the second code, I let all received data contain warning, the result is that the first message contains the whole output string, but after the first, all received messages are trimmed (maybe due to the data was not completely transformed to string before start sending string)

Note: The data are sent from Arduino every one second, and the data in the scrollview text appears correctly 100% (this indicates that the data was transformed to String but maybe the problem is that it takes time)

So please help or make suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem
The problem is that android cannot read the whole data sent from arduino (using Serial.print ()) by a single bulktransfer () function call, so I make the bulktransfer () (or read) in a while loop, then I check on each Sting sent by arduino by building a String when each new line ("\n") is detected in the readed data